# Images in the post still pointing to older domain after domain change

Tags: migration

I configured a new Domain for WordPress on Google Cloud Platform. It took around 24hrs for DNS propagation. Upon checking posts on the site I found that all the images are still pointing to the older domain, except a few images. Under the general tab in Setting, I can see that "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" display the new domain.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Image URLs are just saved as HTML in the database. They're not going to change just by changing the site URL. You need to do some sort of search-replace. This is covered in the documentation on moving WordPress:

> When your domain name or URLs change there are additional concerns.
> The files and database can be moved, however references to the old
> domain name or location will remain in the database, and that can
> cause issues with links or theme display.
>
> If you do a search and replace on your entire database to change the
> URLs, you can cause issues with data serialization, due to the fact
> that some themes and widgets store values with the length of your URL
> marked. When this changes, things break. To avoid that serialization
> issue, you have three options:
>
> 1. Use the [Velvet Blues Update URLs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) or [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugins if
>    you can access your Dashboard.
> 2. Use [WP-CLI’s search-replace](http://wp-cli.org/commands/search-replace/) if your hosting provider (or you) have
>    installed WP-CLI.
> 3. Use the [Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) to safely
>    change all instances on your old domain or path to your new one. (**
>    only use this option if you are comfortable with database
>    administration ** )

https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/

Comment: Why in some posts it got replaced automatically, as you can see in the screenshot. Will follow the steps you mentioned, Thanks.

Comment: Images that are attached to posts by their ID and rendered by a template based on the ID will not need to be replaced because the URL is generated dynamically. Also, any images that are inserted using a relative URL will continue to work if the domain is changed because they're not pointing at a particular URL. If a full image URL is hard-coded into content then that will need to be replaced manually. I can't say which applies to you based on the screenshot alone.